# H (observation) matrix in Kalman Filter when only measuring some of the state-space variables

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I'm implementing a Kalman filter for an 2D tracked object. I'm measuring the position and the velocity of the object. For the moment, I assume I have all the data from the sensors at the same time, so my observation matrix H is 
H = eye(4,4), a 4x4 identity matrix. (See code below)

However, in my final implementation I will have the data from the sensors at different times. So in some update loops I will have the velocity, and in others I will have the position. How would I write the H matrix in those cases?

Is it okay to write 
[position loop]

```
[1, 0, 0, 0 ]
[0, 1, 0, 0 ]
[0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

[velocity loop]

```
[0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[0, 0, 0, 0 ]
[0, 0, 1, 0 ]
[0, 0, 0, 1 ]
```

Note that my state space variables are [x, y, vx, vy]

I wonder if using those matrices does not imply that my observations are zero, or something like that.

Can I leave the covariances matrices untouched? I guess not.

```
#Implementation of 2D filter with FilterPy.

import numpy as np
from filterpy.kalman import KalmanFilter
from filterpy.common import Q_discrete_white_noise
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# --------- PARAM -----------

dt = 0.1

v_dev = 0.3

pos_dev = 0.8

duration = 50

acceleration_noise = 0.3
# --------- MODEL ------------

transition_matrix = [[1,0,dt,0],[0,1,0,dt],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]

transition_covariance = np.array([
[ 0.25*pow(dt, 4), 0, 0.5* pow(dt, 3), 0 ],
[ 0, 0.25*pow(dt, 4), 0, 0.5* pow(dt, 3)],
[ 0.5* pow(dt, 3), 0, dt*dt, 0],
[ 0, 0.5*dt*dt*dt, 0, dt*dt]]) * acceleration_noise *acceleration_noise # A large process noise favors the measurements. ()

#Transition matrix with acceleration componentn

observation_matrix = np.eye(4, 4)

initial_state = [0, 0, 0.5, 0.5]

initial_state_covariance = [[ pos_dev*pos_dev, 0, 0 ,0],[0, pos_dev*pos_dev, 0, 0],[0, 0, v_dev * v_dev, 0 ],[0, 0, 0, v_dev * v_dev ]]


observation_covariance =  [[pos_dev * pos_dev , 0, 0 ,0],[0, pos_dev * pos_dev, 0, 0],[0, 0, v_dev * v_dev, 0 ],[0, 0, 0, v_dev * v_dev ]]

#-----------------------------

#---------- FAKE DATA ---------

ind = np.array( range( round(duration/dt) ) )
time = ind * dt

position = np.zeros( (2, len(ind)) ) 
position[0,:] = time
position[1,:] = 3 * np.sin(time)

noise = pos_dev * np.random.randn(2, len(ind))
noisy_pos = position + noise

vel = position[:,1:len(ind)] - position[:,0:len(ind)-1]
vel = vel / dt

vel_ind = np.zeros( (2, len(ind) -1 )  )
vel_ind[0,:] = position[0,0:len(ind)-1]
vel_ind[1,:] = position[1,0:len(ind)-1]

vel_noise = v_dev * np.random.randn(2, len(ind) - 1 )
noisy_vel = vel + vel_noise

observations = np.zeros((len(ind), 4))

observations[:,[0,1]] = np.transpose(noisy_pos)
observations[1:len(ind),[2,3]] = np.transpose(noisy_vel)
observations[0,[2,3]] = np.transpose(noisy_vel[[0,1],0] )

# KALMAN!

filtered_state_means = np.zeros((len(time), 4))
filtered_state_covariances = np.zeros( ( len(time), 4, 4) )



kf = KalmanFilter( dim_x = 4, dim_z = 4) # state space: x, y, vx, vy, measuring all

kf.x = np.array( initial_state )
kf.F = np.array( transition_matrix )
kf.H = np.array( observation_matrix )
kf.P = np.array( initial_state_covariance )
kf.Q = np.array( transition_covariance )
kf.R =np.array( observation_covariance ) #measurement covariance

for i in range(0, len(time) ):

    # Ommitting some data points

    if( i > no_gps_start and i < no_gps_end):

        # No data from gps
        kf.H = np.array( ([0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]) )
    else:
        kf.H = observation_matrix 

    kf.predict()
    kf.update(observations[i])

    filtered_state_means[i] = kf.x
    filtered_state_covariances[i] = kf.P

# Plotting everything

xmin = -2
xmax = 22
ymin = -4.3
ymax = 4.3

axisLimits = [xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax]


plt.figure(1)
plt.plot( position[0,:], position[1,:], linewidth=1 , color= '0.7')
plt.plot( noisy_pos[0,:], noisy_pos[1,:], '.')
plt.axis( axisLimits )


plt.figure(2)
plt.plot( position[0,:], position[1,:], linewidth=1 , color= '0.7')
plt.quiver( vel_ind[0,:], vel_ind[1,:], noisy_vel[0,:], noisy_vel[1,:], angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=10)
plt.axis( axisLimits )


plt.figure(3)
plt.plot( position[0,:], position[1,:], linewidth=1 , color= '0.7', zorder= 1)
plt.plot( filtered_state_means[:,0], filtered_state_means[:,1], linewidth = 1, zorder= 2)
plt.plot( noisy_pos[0,:], noisy_pos[1,:], '.', color = "#fd92f8", zorder= 0)

plt.plot( no_gps_x, no_gps_y, 'ro')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you are not allowed to modify the observation matrix in this way.

In your case the best solution would be a sequential Kalman Filter, which was developed exactly for handling of missing measurements. The measurement vector is replaced through a sequence of separate scalar measurements. The filter can proceed them independently and is not corrupted if one or more measurements do not exist at some point in time.

Have a look at Dan Simon's "Optimal State Estimation" Chapter 6.1 (you can try to find the book online). He derives alternative equations for the Kalman Filter, which are pretty easy to implement. The prediction step stays the same, you need to modify the update step.

**Pros:**

- you don't need to compute the inverse matrix at all (nice for embedded systems)
- if your H matrix has a lot of zeros the equivalent sequential expressions are very short and computationally efficient

**Contras:**

- the R matrix (measurement covariance) has to be diagonal

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to skim through the book. I'd prefer to use someone else's implementation, though. I tried pykalman, that says it has support for "masked" values, but results looked like data dived to zero when I masked the values. I discarded that library because the lack of support.

Comment: I see. So far I haven't seen any library which implements the sequential Kalman Filter.